# unable to correctly map json to data model

Tags: javascript, json, angular6

I want to model the following information into `json` but am unable to do so.

The server sends result of an operation to the client using the following model

```
class Result (result:string, additional-info:string)
```

`additional-info` could contain a `json` or a `string` depending on the use case. Thus its type is `String`. When I need to send a `json` in it, I simply send a string with a valid `json` syntax and I suppose the the `Angular` client would be able to convert the string into a `json` using `JSON.parse`.

The `json` I want to send to the client looks like

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "additional-info": {
        "list ": [{
            "tag": "sometag",
            "description": "some description"
        }]
    }
}
```

I checked on jsonlint (https://jsonlint.com/) that the structure is correct.

On the client side (`Angular`), I am handing the message as follows:

```
  getQuestions(some args){
      console.log('response from server:',res)
      console.log('response body',res.body)
      let jsonResponse:ServerResponseAPI = res.body //should contain result and additional info
      console.log("result: "+jsonResponse.result+", additional info:"+jsonResponse.additionalInformation)
      let jsonList:string = jsonResponse.additionalInformation
      console.log("jsonQuestionList: "+jsonList)
      let information:Information = JSON.parse(jsonList)
      console.log("information:"+information)
    });
  }
```

`ServerResponseAPI` is defined as

```
export class ServerResponseAPI{ 
  constructor ( public result:string,
               public additionalInformation:string){}
}
```

When I execute the code, I see the following prints on browser's console but I see that error that `additional-info` is not define.

`response body {result: "success", additional-info: "{"list ": [{"tag": "sometag",  "description": "some description"}]}"}
list-management.service.ts:46 result: success, additional info:undefined`

I can see that the body contains `result` and `additional-info` but after casting the body to `ServerResponseAPI`, I see that `result` is `success` but `additional-info` is undefined.

Comment: Please, post the code with which you create the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `res.body`, javascript creates an object

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "additional-info": {
        "list ": [{
            "tag": "sometag",
            "description": "some description"
        }]
    }
}
```

The object has two keys - `result` and `additional-info`. Lets call it `Object1`

I assign it to an object which has keys `result` and `additionalInfo`. Note the difference in naming convention in `additionalInfo`. In javascript, names of variables are case sensitive, so the above two are different. Lets call this `object2`

Now `result` from `object1` gets assigned to `result` from `object2` because the keys match (same name `result`)
`additional-info` becomes a new key in the `object2` 
`additionalInfo` key of `object2` stays undefined as no key from `object1` maps to `additionalInfo`

To solve the issue, I had to create a `additional-info` key `ServerResponseAPI` (alternatively I could have also changed my JSON property name to `additionalInfo` but I didn't want to change that). This is done in Angular as

```
export class ServerResponseAPI{
  'additional-info':string;
  constructor ( public result:string,
               public additionalInformation:string){
    this['additional-info'] = additionalInformation;
  }
}
```

In my code, I now access the keys as

```
let jsonResponse:ServerResponseAPI = res.body //contains result and additional info
      console.log("result: "+jsonResponse.result+", additional info:"+jsonResponse['additional-info'])
      let jsonQuestionList:string = jsonResponse['additional-info']
```